# Check if number is a sum of consecutive numbers or not

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Write a program that checks if a given positive integer can be represented as sum of two or more consecutive positive integers.

#### Example:

43 can be represented as 21 + 22

10 = 1+2+3+4

but 4 cannot be represented in this way.

**Input spec:**  positive integer (as argument or stdin)

**Output spec:** truthy or falsy

#### Sample i/o

```
43 -> true
4 -> false
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: I assume `./check 1` should return `false`?

Comment: @mellamokb, I've fixed the spec and it's now clear that `1` gives false.

Comment: Is case important for the output?

Comment: Not really, that should not be a problem :)

Comment: Any odd number greater than 1 would return true?

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer, and only code-golf.

Comment: Good edit, @mbomb007

Comment: [Related OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A138591)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### JavaScript (31)

```
alert(!!((n=~~prompt())&(n-1)))
```

From my testing, I believe this gives correct solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/3e9FZ/

**Edit**: (SPOILER ALERT!) Here is the justification for this answer:

1. All odd numbers greater than 1 can be trivially written as the sum of two consecutive numbers (ex 15 = 7+8, 23=11+12, etc.).
2. For even numbers having an odd factor where the odd factor is less than twice the even factor.  For example, 4*7, because 7 < (2*4 = 8).  Simply add 7 numbers with 4 at the center, 1+2+3+4+5+6+7.
3. For even numbers having an odd factor where the odd factor is more than twice the even factor.  For example, 4*9, because 9 > (2 * 4 = 8).  Double the even factor, and halve the odd factor to get 8*4.5.  You will add the 8 numbers centered at 4.5, i.e., 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8.
4. The only numbers left are the even numbers having no odd factor, i.e., the powers of two.  The formula for the sum of a consecutive set of numbers is (avg * count).  Now if the count is odd, then avg is a whole number, and (avg * count) has an odd factor.  If count is even, then avg must be #.5, and thus avg * 2 is odd, and so avg * count has an odd factor.  Therefore, any sum using the formula (avg * count) must have an odd factor, which powers of two do not, and therefore have no solution.

Comment: It easy to see that odd numbers can be written as a sum of two consecutive numbers, and therefore any number that's not a power of two can be written as a sum of consecutive numbers.

Comment: How do you get from "all odd numbers" to "all numbers that are not a power of 2" ?

Comment: @Paul R: I have updated the answer with justification for why this should be correct.

Comment: @Alexandru: That is the basic idea, but you can't jump directly to powers of 2 without covering all the cases as I've given above with rules #2 and #3.

Comment: +1 for the proof (although to be pedantic, all odd numbers greater than 1).

Comment: @mellamokb: to be pedantic you still need to prove lack of solution for powers of two.

Comment: @Alexandru, @Peter Taylor: Duly updated, thanks for the input!

Comment: Bloody brilliant

Comment: About the JavaScript code: Does JavaScript guarantee strict left-to-right evaluation of the arguments to `&`? In C that expression would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: What's your source?  According to sources I found by Googling, both [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and [C](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) have operator precendence charts listing `&` as left-to-right associative.  Why would it be undefined behavior?

Comment: great work with the math man!

Comment: You can change it to an anonymous function: `x=>!!(x&x-1)` (12 bytes)

Comment: Edit: you can also get rid of the `!!()`, because positive integer values are considered truthy. This yields `x=>x&x-1` (8 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

#### Golfscript, 20 chars

```
~.(&!!"falsetrue"5/=
```

Someone had to.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby (23)

only 3 chars longer than golfscript :)

```rb
p 0<(n=$*[0].to_i)&n-1
```

output:

```
$ ruby gc2958.rb 4
false
$ ruby gc2958.rb 43
true
$ wc gc2958.rb
  1       2      23 gc2958.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 74

Felt like doing the brute force way.

```
import List
main=print.f=<<readLn
f n=elem n$map sum$tails=<<inits[1..n-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (81)

```
n=prompt(r=i=1)|0;while(r&++i*i/2<n)if(i%2&!(n%i)|!(i%2|(n+i/2)%i))r=!r;alert(!r)
```

I'm cheating with `&` and `|` - even though they are technically bit-wise operations, they do the job quite nicely because the result is a 1/0 which are valid conditionals!

http://jsfiddle.net/HCqK2/4/

Answer (score 1):

### C, 67

As mellamokb suggested all numbers, except powers of two, can be written as sum of positive consecutive numbers:

```
main(int i,char**a){
printf((i=atoi(a[1]))&i-1?"true\n":"false\n");
}
```

Comment: your kinda stealing his idea...

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3 REPL, 34

```
bool(int(bin(2*int(input()))[3:]))
```

I took an alternative approach to the solution, but can't seem to squeeze anything else out of it. This code takes the input, multiplies it by two (this fixes the input case of `1` which breaks otherwise), converts it to binary, strips out the first 3 characters (`0b1`), converts the remainder to an integer (which is 0 iff the input was a power of two), and then converts that to a boolean.

As mentioned above, you can remove the `2*` to get a 32-char solution that fails on an input of `1` but is otherwise perfect.

Comment: i assume you need a truthy value, so the `bool()` is not needed?

Answer (score 1):

### C

return 1 or 0:

```
int i(int j){return((j%2)?!(j==1):i(j/2));}
```

Comment: doesnt fulfill the task - it has to output "true" or "false".

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 REPL, 24 chars

Shortest python atm, borrowing `bin()` from @Fraxtil :)

```
bin(input()).count('1')>1
```

Comment: `bin(input()).count('1')>=2`?

Comment: Haha, that's kinda obvious really :D thanks. And `>=2` == `>1` ;)

Comment: Is this not repl snippet?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 REPL, <strike>19</strike> <strike>17</strike> 16

```
x=input()
x>x&-x
```

Comment: Nice. You can actually shave off two characters on the second line: `~-x&x>0`

Comment: @daniero Nice trick!!

Comment: `x&-x<x` saves yet 1 character

Comment: @AMK great trick!! updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
N[2~Log~#]~MatchQ~_Real
```

For once it's actually useful

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

```
fPart(logBASE(Ans,2
```

Operating system ≥2.53 required due to `logBASE(`. Without logBASE, there are alternatives:

```
7 bytes: fPart(ln(Ans)/ln(2
7 bytes: fPart(log(Ans)/log(2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93, 28 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JnZALjE8QC4wPAo6PC8yX14jIV9eIy0xXCUyOg&input=NDM)

```
&v@.1<@.0<
:</2_^#!_^#-1\%2:
```

Instead of checking if the given integer is an element in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A138591), it's much easier to check if it isn't in the [complimentary sequence](http://oeis.org/A155559) (powers of 2 with 0 instead of 1). This functions very similarly to mellamokb's answer in that sense.

Note that the linked sequences are not exact representations of all truthy/falsey results of each integer, because the sequence uses non-negative integers instead of strictly positive. Thus, 1 *is* in the linked sequence, even though for this specific problem it should be in its compliment.

Comment: not actually the powers of two... It is actually the powers of two with 1 replaced by 0

Comment: also you are using the wrong sequence. that one includes 1 as a number by virtue of 1+0, as it uses non negative rather than positive

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon I realize that the sequence doesn't completely match the problem, but only in regards to the base case of 1. The complimentary sequence for the one that matches the problem is the powers of 2 (possibly in addition to 0, depending on where the sequence starts).

Comment: Why don't you just use the actual powers of two instead of that sequence of two? (0 is not a positive number anyway, so no need to cover it)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>18</del> 17 bytes

Umm, it's shorter than GolfScript...

```
Fn.new{|n|n&-n<n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiavJk9NN88mr/Z/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqRqJecmJOjoaJqabmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
‹⋏
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLnii48iLCIiLCI0MyJd)

Just a port of Jelly and JS. Bitwise AND with n-1. Returns positive integer for true, 0 for false.

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 13 bytes

```
\N:-0<N-1/\N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P8bPStfAxk/XUD/GTw/INTLV44ox0QMA)

-4 thanks to Jo King

Comment: the prolog could just be `0<N-1/\N`

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), 7 bytes

```
0≠1|2∘⍟
```

Checks if a number is not a power of 2.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWux_1TX3UNkHD4FHnAsMao0cdMx71ztc8tMLEWMEEogKqEKYBAA)

```
    2∘⍟  log base 2 of
  1|     mod 1
0≠       is not zero
```

My 14-byte brute-force attempt before learning that the question is equivalent to asking if a number is not a power of 2:

```
⊢∊∘∊1↓+/¨∘⊂⍥⍳⍨
```

Using 3 as an example:

```
             ⍨  put the argument on both sides: 3 ... 3
           ⍥⍳   integers from 1 to n on both sides: 1 2 3 ... 1 2 3
      +/¨∘⊂     sums of length-1, 2, and 3 windows in 1 2 3: (1 2 3)(3 5)(6)
    1↓          drop the length-1 sums
   ∊            flatten into a list
⊢∊∘             is the argument in this list?
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 REPL, 33 chars

It seems that there's a way shorter way to do this though:

```
s=input()
n=2
while n<s:n*=2
n!=s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 51 bytes

```
print(((log($ARGV[0])/log(2))=~ /\./ )?true:false);
```

Example:

```
$perl Soc.pl 45

true

$perl Soc.pl 8

false
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 12

It doesn't follow the spec 'true'/'false'. Rather I stick with 1/0. It checks if log base 2 of a number has a decimal mark.

`+/=&'.'":2^.`

```
   +/=&'.'":2^.1
0
   +/=&'.'":2^.4
0
   +/=&'.'":2^.43
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
&’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/tUcPM/4fbHzWtifz/38QYAA)

Just a translation of the accepted JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Ṅ's¯1J≈;Ṫḃ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmEJ3PCrzFK4omIO+G5quG4gyIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xMVxuMTJcbjEzXG4xNFxuMTVcbjE2XG4xN1xuMThcbjE5XG4yMCJd)

A non-bitwise answer that doesn't port Javascript.

### Explained

```
Ṅ's¯1J≈;Ṫḃ
Ṅ           # Integer partitions of the input
 '     ;    # Filtered by:
  s¯        #  Are the deltas of the sorted partition
    1J≈     #  All 1?
        Ṫḃ  # Remove the tail of the list because that's just the input as a single item and then return whether there's any items in the list.
```

Comment: You can use `₃` instead of `Ṫḃ` (using reversed booleans).