# Can the chefs go?

Tags: code-golf, string

On the TV cooking show [Guy's Grocery Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy%27s_Grocery_Games), the chefs cannot begin shopping until Guy Fieri, the show's host, says "Three, two, one, go!" However, the words do not have to be all together. He often "hides" the words in things like this (based on a real example, but not quoting verbatim):

> There are *three* of you here; after this round there will be *two*; but only *one* of you will *go* shop for up to $20,000.

(At the end of the show, the winning chef must find either five or ten items, depending on the episode, from the store; the number of items found determines how much money they win.)

Fairly regularly, he succeeds in confusing the chefs and they don't go. Often, they realize after a few seconds that they can go and frantically run down the aisles trying to make up for the lost time; other times, they don't realize it until the judges start shouting "Go! Go! Go!"

Can you do better?

Write a program that determines

1. Whether the input string allows the chefs to go, and
2. If so, at what point in the string they may go.

The chefs may go if the string contains `three`, followed by zero or more other characters, followed by `two`, followed by zero or more other characters, followed by `one`, followed by zero or more other characters, followed by `go`. Matching is case-insensitive.

The point at which the chefs may go is the zero-based index of the `o` in `go`.

Because `ThreeTwoOneGo` is 13 characters, this number will always be at least 12. If the chefs can go, return the point at which they can go. If they cannot, return no value, any falsy value, or any number of your choice less than or equal to 11. This number does not need to be consistent; it's okay if it varies randomly and/or with the input, as long as it is consistently less than or equal to 11.

Comment: If there is more than one "go" (e.g. "three two one go go go!") then does it matter which one is chosen?

Comment: So the cooks gan go if they say "Three twos onerous gone"? :/

Comment: @Neil it would be the first one.

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, they can, at least for the purposes of this challenge. I think Guy has actually done something like that before, and it counted.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I like this one: “three-dimensional creditworthiness of psychoneuroimmunologists is better than that of otorhinolaryngologists”

Comment: ..."Healthy **three**somes ou**two**rk n**onego**s".

Comment: I guess there is no need to handle multiline input.

Comment: @manatwork single-line-only is acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

## R, 51 bytes

`regexpr("three.*two.*one.*g\\Ko",scan(,""),,T)[1]-1`

Thanks to Bbrk24 for pointing out that `\K` (you have to use an extra backslash in R) sets where the match is considered to start.

R has a lot of built in regex functions, and this one handily tells you where the first match starts (-1 if there is no match). It's 1-indexed though, so we have to take 1 off (and hence, if the chefs can't go, -2 is returned, but that's less than 11 so we're good).

We need to specify `perl=TRUE` to use the `\K` feature. It's cheapest to specify that positionally rather than use `pe=T`.

[image: two example cases where the code returns 25 for a string where the cooks can go, and -2 for a case where they can't go at all]

Depending on conventions for how the input is available, the `scan(,"")` could turn into a variable (e.g. `x`) or function (`\(x)`) saving 8 or 4 bytes respectively.

Comment: You could take input as a function, not as a variable though

Comment: Nice. A link to let others see it in action (e.g. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY4xboRADEX7nGJCBStmIro0OUHa7cIWLJhhJMZe2UaBs2zDRkqZA-U2GURo_C35PfnfH7x-9W_fk_b29felzueCwcN84zzTgQHcST_JnQjT5uv6nbJyLstz8VFdbPWv_fQH7NxGO7fhznl6zoqn42i7EAElEDajaRm6kFjWISCIGOrNTZZ2SObEFGKckEbyQVRMEHMFVWCjQ4Pb0I0nJU42jQ0v6A96_ygUwSChjY22CfJGlFOkQnvpdd3zDw)) is helpful

Comment: Actually current answer fails where words are repeated. R, 50 bytes: [`\(x)regexpr("three.*?two.*?one.*?g\\Ko",x,,T)[1]-1`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Zc8xTsNQDAbgvadwMzUoQSpTl4oDdO1GGELqvDwpz45sR6RnYQlIXIKbcBscpZ1YbMv6fln--JT5qz1-j9aWh9-najflggGnQXaZdYL4-PBs7-yVaZlDVZ04K6aiOOcv-9dyf0v-tDcPrsEtBIZ_i8BZvrnL8hITkkamuodG8BJdinWRUBW4hUGvTefJUTimNBL3HKKaQlR4QzMUv1DTUmzxbCye5r6WK4W7Xi8qJwRiKlNtjaMAauJtm-XrB_O89j8)

Comment: And a further +1 byte to fix the requirement to be case-insensitive: R, 51 bytes: [`\(x)regexpr("three.*?two.*?one.*?g\\Ko",x,T,T)[1]-1`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY8xTsRADEV7TmGmSlCCtKLZZsUBaNMRipD1TEbK2CvbEdmz0GRX4hLchNswUZaKxt-y3rPlz4ssV3_4mszX-5-ntphLwYDzSQpngyA-PjzbB-fKtPahbV_YVXPVVE35unurdzf12xeuWQXIOGQYAsO_QWBX3vnb6voYE5JGpm6EXvAYMyk2REJVYA8nPfdDNifhmNJEPHKIagpR4R3NUMCGjtZiK8_Gkm0eOzlT-KO3i8oJgZjq1FmfoQBqkuPeldsHy7LlLw)

Comment: @Nick Kennedy, do you have an example where repeated words causes an incorrect answer? I've tried some and they all seem to work fine.

Comment: The first example in my previous comment (Three two one go Three two one go go) will fail on your current code for two reasons: 1. The case sensitivity and 2. The greedy matching. (Try "three two one go three two one go" to observe the second problem in isolation.)

Comment: Couldn’t you get rid of the `-1` on the end by matching `\Kgo` rather than `g\Ko`?

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 34 bytes

Returns `0` on invalid inputs. Performs a match against the input, using the result to decrement the last position of the match, [via `@+`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@+), by `1` (on successful matches, otherwise `0`).

```perl
$_=-/three.*?two.*?one.*?go/i+"@+"
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89LS90aHJlZS4qP3R3by4qP29uZS4qP2dvL2krXCJAK1wiIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wbCIsImlucHV0IjoiVGhlcmUgYXJlIHRocmVlIG9mIHlvdSBoZXJlOyBhZnRlciB0aGlzIHJvdW5kIHRoZXJlIHdpbGwgYmUgdHdvOyBidXQgb25seSBvbmUgb2YgeW91IHdpbGwgZ28gc2hvcCBmb3IgdXAgdG8gJDIwLDAwMC5cblRocmVlVHdvT25lR29cblRocmVlVHdvT25lR29nb2dvZ29nb2dvZ29nb2dvIVxudGhyZWV0d29vbmVnb3RocmVldHdvb25lZ29cblRocmVlIGh1bmRyZWQgYW5kIHR3byBpcyBhIGJpZyBudW1iZXIgZm9yIG9uZSwgZ29vZCBqb2IhXG5UaHJlZSwgdHdvLCBvbmUuLi4gc3RvcCJ9)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES11), 40 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to [InSync](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/117141/insync)*

Returns -1 for invalid inputs.

```javascript
s=>s.search(/(?<=three.*two.*one.*g)o/i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lU9LDoIwEN17iglxUYgW4soE0Ut4AT5TIGk6pJ8QzuKGGD2Pa29jC8a9i_lk5r03b24PRQ3Od1E8nRX745uZ4my4wVLXHUvZ5VTYTiPyxI7EE1K-a2NK-_iLf9WkDEnkklomWHTtUCOUPhYekICJHIRpDqWwqP2iN6DJqca3AT32UkLlGSPlUDkLpOTk04-9AFoC09EAgjS4ASzB9pDtsizjURxv_rERTvjLQW4E76UuVY0SmyC0vjXPa_0A)

#### Method

Using a lookbehind assertion, we look for the position of the first `"o"` in the input string which is preceded by the pattern `"three.*two.*one.*g"`.

Comment: I am deeply jealous that R's regex parser doesn't allow variable length regexes (i.e. no `.*`) in look-behind assertions!

Comment: @JDL The workaround for that in some regex engines is to use `\K` instead, which resets where the match is considered to start. Go try `/three.*two.*one.*g\Ko/i` on regex101 with PCRE2, for example.

Comment: oh nice, I didn't know that one. That helps, thanks! (The best I could come up with otherwise was to reverse the whole thing and look for "og.*eno.*owt.*eehrt", which is not particularly golfy in R)

Comment: -6 bytes with [`.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search): `s=>s.search(/(?<=three.*two.*one.*g)o/i)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 24 bytes

```
ʀ"ỌṚUmn»\6”Ṃ".*?"j∥ẋMṪL+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLKgFwi4buM4bmaVW1uwrtcXDbigJ3huYJcIi4qP1wiauKIpeG6i03huapMKyIsIiIsIlRoZXJlIGFyZSB0aHJlZSBvZiB5b3UgaGVyZTsgYWZ0ZXIgdGhpcyByb3VuZCB0aGVyZSB3aWxsIGJlIHR3bzsgYnV0IG9ubHkgb25lIG9mIHlvdSB3aWxsIGdvIHNob3AgZm9yIHVwIHRvICQyMCwwMDAuIiwiMy4yLjAiXQ==) | [Literate mode equivalent (doesn't work)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJsb3dlciBcIuG7jOG5mlVtbsK7XFw24oCdIHNwbGl0LXNwYWNlIFwiLio/XCIgam9pbi1vbiBwYXJhbGxlbC1hcHBseSByZS1zZWFyY2ggcmUtbWF0Y2ggcmVtb3ZlLWxhc3QgbGVuIGFkZCIsIiIsIlRocmVldHdvb25lZ28gdGhyZWUgdHdvIG9uZSBnbyIsIjMuMi4wIl0=)

**Explanation**:

```
ʀ"ỌṚUmn»\6”Ṃ".*?"j∥ẋMṪL+­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
 "ỌṚUmn»\6”Ṃ".*?"j        # ‎⁡Split "ỌṚUmn»\6” ("three two one go") on spaces and join by ".*?"
ʀ                 ∥ẋM     # ‎⁢Parallel apply regex search and regex match to lowercased input
                     ṪL+  # ‎⁣Add length - 1 to index
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: This looks for the last "go" of several valid matches, which is incorrect according to a comment of the OP.

Comment: @Neil ty for letting me know

Comment: Your Literate link is still out of date and neither work on `threetwoonegoonego`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 25 bytes

```
I^iw0`three.*two.*one.*go
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xCsMwFEOvokKnUIzbNQconbpkLkmoHRuMFRwbk9O7Pxk66CO@9FAy2cfp3trr46ses0vGqC5Xqo5R3MLWBmeSwSQ6Y9BiZ8Hx7THZbJIEfkNiiV@xR7v6EDALUdljLhmMYZfzp8/CQmyOKywTyopMXB/6prVWGM6poRJvgZ68/AA)

The regex is pretty straightforward, all the magic comes from the configuration flags at the beginning:

- `I`: find the position of the matches
- `^`: use the position of the last character instead of the first
- `i`: case insensitive
- `w`: do this for all possible ways (even overlapping) of matching this regex
- `0`: return only the first one

In practice, `w0` will make sure that we return the earliest possible complete match, and is shorter than any other option based on lazy matching (`.*?`)

Comment: Wow, I've never seen an `I` stage before!

Comment: Doesn't this return 1-based indexes?

Comment: I've since double-checked and @TwiNight used an I stage [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251933). I didn't see it though because it's a relatively recent answer to an old question.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 36 bytes

```
i1M!`.*?three.*?two.*?one.*?g(?=o)
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETvfsUILVgpkvYqxaOn0osfoNKoAclITAh@fZp46GFnh903jJFW6SFci7YP6vHO@6ps7GKkTNszKnXyc9G8eMuqELpFGokhzsmBEw46pGuNYbLSxIfaYej0N9pEe7WuGGPCs8boLKjXI8o/fQIzsS/cMNHAbbDE5SnuQogq@0S080R3VrbMfw) Link includes test cases. Outputs `0` for disallowed inputs. Explanation:

```
i1M!`.*?three.*?two.*?one.*?g(?=o)
```

Keep only the text up to the `g` of `go` (or delete the text entirely if it doesn't contain the words in the right order).

```
.
```

Count the number of characters remaining.

Comment: If "three two one go" appears more than once in the input this will return the position of the last one, not the first one: https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv/YoRWrClSOhVSo@eSi9@gEqjBiQjMSH49enGQw87O@zOY5z2xvbpUjZdMu@iq24vPzut844Upc1@Kl9PXk9VSu2snUYvc@TAETsD8rVGP3rt5GE2OAb7FZvT0SwLBiEiawzBg3bZRf70EZiIbeaKkQ5hhSfOD3VXSlVoj6o2Eh@BGhY/

Comment: @Leo Nice spot, I forgot Retina defaults to returning all matches, so it was adding up all of the lengths of all of the matches. Fixed at a cost of a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 77 bytes

```scala
s=>new Regex("(?i)(?<=three.*two.*one.*g)o").findFirstMatchIn(s).map(_.start)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZDPSsNAEMbxmouv8BE87BYbgl6kNS1ehB6K4J9TKLJNNslKuhs2E9MifRIvXvTiE9WncZNIH8CF2R1mvvn2x7x_1YkoxeV37I-1aYXV_uoQq01lLKFvBQ2pMtgISgql8-Be5nLreWb9IhPCUiiNN88DXkWJTOl0oVO5nYA9kHVyRDPcVaSMjheaVhzRZ0PZ-OqwrKOZli16O-azueJsfh1RYaUMRtSaYGS0y3JufB50xrfK1rTsMBaa1dwRVew5qElY4oPpz8kpkMoMG0fFhM3rCW6sFbt4gFnxCZ60IkQOGe5UrkqlZkdu5j8W0koIFz0KTIadadBVpxAZSesaqoY1jU5d2qlbVZZYu4nWTLFuCEaXO3cdp3tBblAXpkJmLJoKZHB2EZ6HYRj4nP8Lp_vKEXS2LRxTInQiS5n-Ge69_bCXj4_h_QU)

Comment: I see there an `"i"` parameter passed on the `Regex` instantiation, but the code still seems to match case sensitively. Attempt This Online says it also uses Scala 3, so I guess is not version mismatch. Maybe different build of the interpreter?

Comment: @manatwork Thank you, now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
“Ç<*tẉ{cIE»Ḳṫw¥ƒŒlL’ȧạ¥L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcshDsJAEEDRqyyWhBtgESS9RGmH7pLtDNmZpmkwOIKtI8EgGgQOBcWVQLjG9iILNZiv3l@BtVUI/fb43E3H4tv9JpnPuoe/Xf39UnbNu37VNuq3h8/Zt6euiUIIoh3AJDU5IBvC2KrEQWqkJCfaIDArWqo1V4kmhMKRyfMCyVJmWFgZVgsQAadExzhEBk9C7neTjV2F2V9nNPoC)

A monadic link taking a string and returning an integer.

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for pointing out the case-insensitive requirement!*

### Explanation

```
“Ç<*tẉ{cIE»Ḳ              | Compressed string "three two one go" split at spaces
            ṫw¥ƒŒl        | Reduce, starting with the main link argument lower-cased, then for each of the strings above, find the first position in the current string and take the tail starting from there
                   L      | Length
                    ’     | Decrease by 1
                     ȧạ¥L | And with absolute difference from this and the length of the original string
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, very similar! I've corrected mine to handle the case-insensitivity requirement. I'd been looking at the (currently) top R answer which used a case sensitive regex; although my answer is completely different, I think I'd assumed therefore that the case didn't matter and hadn't gone back to check that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>39</s> 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
lηÅΔηU“„í‚•€µ‚œ“#εXsδÅ¿ƶ0K}.«âε˜D{Q}à
```

What a mess.. Once again I hate that 05AB1E lacks a builtin to get all matching indices, instead of only the first.. The `ηU` and `εXsδÅ¿ƶ0K}` are all to do that manually.. -_-

Will output `-1` if it's invalid.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/59z2w63nppzbHvqoYc6jhnmH1z5qmPWoYdGjpjWHtgKZRycDxZXPbY0oPrflcOuh/ce2GXjX6h1afXjRua2n57hUB9YeXvD/v4Z7vqKCf16qQkl5vkJJRlFqqp6mQkhGalGqQiIQp@WXFinkpylU5pcqgAStFRLTSlKLgCozixWK8kvzUoBMkOLyzJwchSSIMRp5@SUQszStFZJKSxTy83IqgUQqzCSw4vR8heKM/AKgFUUKpQUKJfkKKkYGOgYGBnoA) or [verify a few test cases](https://tio.run/##vU69SsRAEO59ivEUvIMQFtsrrhEsBEVQsE3IxizEnWN3kyNoIAjnA6iVHCLXqp3xSiGLNsI@xL5I3FxA38BihuGb7w9lEDLaXuXFZAD25hYGk6JNzUrPzb1ZndpqYatH/WqrB1st7fVLU7vz887hW6Y@k@ZNz5uPr3dyUPrNs16a@nuxd3lc6qe29NqThAoKgRuVCEoBYygwgw4dQxArKtyDSRCY8cidHXvG0hRCp5ghDDmqXjoaQ5gpQJ4Wbv06rcnnCDLBKcQoIJuCQtjeJR4hxN8Y7uMmHPHebW3kj@CvVYyZ@P9SXadDmrucC8Yjr0/r9EzyHQV5kLLI/wE).

**Explanation:**

```python
l                # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 η               # Convert it to a list of prefixes
  ÅΔ             # Get the index of the first prefix that's truthy for
                 # (or -1 if none are):
    η            #  Get the prefixes of the current prefix
     U           #  Pop and store it in variable `X`
    “„í‚•€µ‚œ“   #  Push dictionary string "three two one go"
     #           #  Split it on spaces
      ε          #  Map over all four words:
       X         #   Push the earlier list of prefixes of the prefix
        s        #   Swap so the current word is at the top again
         δ       #   Map over each prefix, using the word as argument:
          Å¿     #    Check whether the prefix ends with the word as substring
            ƶ    #   Multiply each check by its 1-based index
             0K  #   Remove all 0s
      }.«        #  After the map: reduce this list of lists by:
         â       #   Taking the cartesian product of two lists
          ε      #  Map over each combination of values:
           ˜     #   Flatten it to a single list
            D{Q  #   Check if the four indices are in increasing order:
            D    #    Duplicate the list
             {   #    Sort the copy
              Q  #    Check if both lists are still the same
          }à     #  After the map: check if any was truthy
                 # (after which the found index is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“„í‚•€µ‚œ“` is `"three two one go"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
≔θηＦ⪪”↶⌊¶z₂1γmι.Jχ” ≔✂η⌕↧ηιＬη¹η¿⊖ＬηＩ⁻Ｌθ⊖Ｌη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLasMwEEX3@YqL6UICtbjdelVaukqhkP6Aoowtgapx9KjJ16uykyy7GJjHPcPcMVZHw9rX@pqSm4I4K1g57EaOEIfZuyy6bCMR8sLgQJi4U@jQSYkbcvDOkLAKHy6cxJ4Xikan1pEKrsWewpTtVj7L63o3QryTifRDIVOD7pK29Su6kMWbTll8ulDSfXhu7D@MlEOt35YiQbe4HswjLlywdgfoMVNsA5cQuYRTS1f14rzHcTM34Fhyc@gvm80bvQkmRrI8Y31KmZEZDy@96vv@aVcff/0f) Link is to verbose version of code. Does not output anything for disallowed inputs. Explanation:

```
≔θη
```

Make a copy of the input string.

```
Ｆ⪪”....”
```

Loop over the four relevant words.

```
≔✂η⌕↧ηιＬη¹η
```

Slice the string so that it starts at that word. (But if the word is not present, the `Find` returns `-1`, which causes the `Slice` to return the last character.)

```
¿⊖Ｌη
```

If the string still contains at least two characters (which means it begins `go`), then...

```
Ｉ⁻Ｌθ⊖Ｌη
```

Output `1` more than the number of characters removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
s=>(z=/three.*two.*one.*?go/gi).test(s)*z.lastIndex
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVBBTsMwEBRXXrFUHJLIuFG5IFWhZ-58ICVrJ5Llrey10vYrXCIEj4LXsImlHhAcOKy92pnZGe3ru6cOpzfTfCQ2dw-f97F5LM7NmvuAqCseSVfkpdtZWtuh1IyRi1hWZ-3ayE--w2OWfl1tXshHcqgd2cIUq-ceA0IrtWwDMnCiBPN0C61hDAIMEQIl30k7s8fBOdiLYqQt7BMDeXeS56JeCJYg9nQAQwHSAZjgdlOruq71qiyv_44x0r9CiG0OYUlBK_DPHJcQ-Vy_mgugZmc1q9WyKteN0PPppin_3w)

This outputs 0 for no match, or the index.

The `RegExp.lastIndex` property (which only works for RegExes that have the `g` flag enabled) gives the index of the end of the previous match.

Comment: It looks like you can save one byte by removing the "i" in "gi"?

Comment: @Somebody the `i` makes the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Your code returns the 0-based index of the character _after_ the `o` in `go`. Of course, this can also be interpreted as the 1-based index of the `o` in `go` if the OP allows 1-base indexing.

Comment: You code also finds the last "go", which seems incorrect.

Comment: @Neil is that because I used `.*` and not `.*?`? If so, I’ll change it, but you should probably mention it in some other answers since a lot of people seem to have made that mistake.

Comment: What Neil means is that you'll output the 2nd `go` on an input such as `"Three two one go, three two one go"`.

Comment: I'll ask for clarification.

Comment: @Neil Ok, I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>93</s> 77 bytes

I'm new to `regex`, so open to golfs. Returns an integer for truthy and a `None` object for falsy.

```py
lambda n:((x:=re.search("three.*?two.*?one.*?go",n,2))and~-x.end())
import re
```

Comment: [77 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY-_asMwEIf3PsVhApGDY0ymkhC6dsnWsYtsnyyDojPyGcdLX6SLobTv1NfoE_SUpP_ooNNx_O7Tp-e3bmJLfn4x-8fXgc369v3g9LGsNfitUqftPmDeow6VVQnbgJiv7ngkqeRj31CS-WyTptrXT-tTjr5WaXrTHjsKDAGv0I8utJ6VUcsHiwFBy-F7wQEZmGiAON2BNowB2LY9BBp8LW1Mj61zUMrGSDsoBwbybpLyvX0ONAS9pQ4MBRg6YILFpsiKosiXYvQlkPwSsP8EIlzejKARxKLSvkKHdZ78RcRFsTk7NJRdUT8TiV9-Ps-X-xM)

Answer (score 1):

## [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)): <s>119</s> 113 bytes

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{char*s="go\0.one\0two\0three",*p=*++v;for(c=4;c--;)p+=strcasestr(p,s+4*c)-(int)p;exit(++p-*v);}
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone helping in improving the answer! :D

1. As always a minor improvement was made thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) (124 -> 122 bytes).
2. Thanks to [@Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master) for getting rid of the prototype (119 -> 113 bytes).

## [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) ([gcc -m32](https://gcc.gnu.org/)): 105 bytes

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{char*s="go\0.one\0two\0three",*p=*++v;for(c=4;c--;)p=strcasestr(p,s+4*c);exit(++p-*v);}
```

<s>The prototype feels like a huge waste of bytes. Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to work around that. :/</s>

Edit: Using the `-m32` flag you can get rid of the prototype entirely (explained in the comments below). Thanks to [@Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master) for suggesting this trick. :)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVNNj9MwED3TXzHqJf3MglhxoOqBI9KKE5xYDlN7klh17eBxkq0Qf50ydtJSEJHSpOOZN2/evKhtrdTlckLjFmrTL1WDYbXqdz9mINfDAxRcgPIuSgJDbAiOdB580OkPRsBA0KLWpGEwsYGiLIB9Tmy9cZECKHRXsAPByfeSezgDQmVe5LVH2xFED7VPv6nS0Uu89imn2huf9h8@xml6AV8BoWquVbCgnlzs0Nrz31lF7YvlFRQ@VuA8nDBKqWGofOd0bjEYaxPdT1@engAlqLBjEtJM9UmQMRrvoMLOxhvY0JgE47RRGGkSaGzedhG0l5jzopm1fsgHqqGKx9lvKJ8lzvS9I6coceLog8hkHASZKSQSDCYCYy94JzkEblHRCJD3x/t57Z9fl97R8@s4yGtsAtF8s2r3q/W6381ybuXDQu0fd2q73S1z5I5Cg2eOqI6JQhJE5I6EOknYf33zDdgkfrGRY21YYXIEunMmgEr2zveIB6oS0TSzRY6T4qNgbci7EjEtJ9ewiSaNZs2R3t@DzGWUsizzLGUarizrFJjPXok/5IYPWvPkINKWCha6FZNgB3/KY4jW8tiM6gsT42qIwahjrssgyp9aY8W4aS@ULJ5dkRfJLF4VCRrsc6XENCmL02xt8NHHczsCSR7HIF1IHovJdOlq1/u7g3bD68eVWm4X8r0s22k5k9UbzP44JBOpQMl6YobRAf//DIq6uPp87EgvJi7W63a76pe72c/LtGB0PMiQkvrHogdKzuTGd1annm/fXS4Hi42InqSflL@L3LaQYr9UZbHmy3b4DQ)

**Explanation**:

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{
    // 's' contains the keywords that are padded with '.' so the pointer can
    // be moved by a fixed value to go to the next keyword.
    //
    // 'p' contains the index of each keyword (eventually the index of 'go').
    // If no match is found 'p' will be NULL and cause a segmentation fault.
    // which indicates that the input does not allow the chefs to go.
    // The sequence is stored in reverse as it saves more space.
    char*s="go\0.one\0two\0three",*p=*++v;

    for(c=4;c--;)
        // The haystack is 'p' instead of v[1] since this discards any characters
        // before the last match which prevent false positives like:
        // "two...three..one..go..."
        //
        // Adds the needle's offset from 'p' to 'p', the casting tricks the
        // compiler to get around the issue of having the declare the prototype
        // of strcasestr().
        p+=strcasestr(p,s+4*c)-(int)p;

    // 'p' has to be incremented as it contains the index of 'g' of 'go'.
    exit(++p-*v);
}
```

Comment: If you use `-m32` you don't need the prototype.

Comment: @CommandMaster Nice trick! Out of curiosity do you know why this works?

Comment: It makes the program 32 bit, so the size of a pointer is the same as `int` which is the default return value without a prototype

Comment: Even without `-m32` you can do `p+=strcasestr(p,s+4*c)-(int)p;`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Also, nice trick for the non-`-m32` code. :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.6.1, 38 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character/265917#265917)

```
-1⧻⊢⊢regex"(?is).*three.*two.*one.*go"
```

[Try it yourself](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_6_1__JCBUaGVyZSBhcmUgdGhSRUVFRUVFRSBvZiB5b3UgaGVyZTsKJCBhZnRlciB0aGlzIHJvdW5kIHRoZXJlIHdpbGwgYmUgdHdvOwokIGJ1dCBvbmx5IG9uZSBvZiB5b3UKJCB3aWxsIGdvIHNob3AgZm9yIHVwIHRvICQyMCwwMDAuIgoKLTHip7viiqLiiqJyZWdleCIoP2lzKS4qdGhyZWUuKnR3by4qb25lLipnbyIK)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 30 bytes

```
a~-`three.*?two.*?one.*?go`D$)
```

Outputs an index, or nothing if the chefs cannot go. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhfi1gdGhyZWUuKj90d28uKj9vbmUuKj9nb2BEJCkiLCIiLCJcIlRocmVlIHR3b3Mgb25lcm91cyBnb25lIHRocmVldHdvb25lZ29nb2dvXCIiLCIiXQ==)

(Note that this doesn't work on ATO as of posting, and might stop working on DSO in the future, because the way Pip currently handles regex case-insensitivity doesn't play well with newer versions of Python. I may get around to fixing that someday.)

#### Explanation

```lisp
   `three.*?two.*?one.*?go`     ; Regex, with non-greedy quantifiers
  -                             ; Make it case-insensitive
a~                              ; Find the first match in the program argument
                            $)  ; Get the index of the end of that match
                           D    ; Decrement
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 156 bytes

Short version:

```
func c(_ s:String)->Int{let s=s.lowercased();return s.ranges(of: /three.*two.*one.*go/).first.map({s.distance(from:s.startIndex,to:$0.upperBound)-1}) ?? 0}
```

Verbose version:

```
func c2_(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let s = s.lowercased()
    return s.ranges(of: /three.*two.*one.*go/).first.map({
        s.distance(from: s.startIndex, to: $0.upperBound) - 1
    }) ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)’s type system, <s>213</s> 203 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<S,A=0,Z=any,B=Lowercase<S>>=B extends`${Z}three${Z}two${Z}one${Z}go${infer D}`?F<B extends`${infer B}go${D}`?B:0,[1]>:A extends 0?0:S extends`${Z}${infer R}`?F<R,[...A,1]>:A["length"]
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAMQB4BlAGgEEBeABkoC1aBDRHSgIVoBlkA7ulQBjVpHQUAfFNpdC6AB7h0iACaQABgBIA3kwC+4ABYZ0ew+AHILB5InP6D8G7tiIAZsMIARA5oB+MnklFXUtPXcvVEIuZ1c-QK4ALkYAbQBGAF0pZOoFZVUNQnoA+mTyArCNHSdIz28AJX8g0kbKNIA6bupKbNzqNIAiABtVeBMhrMxsfCIAFXRIcAzCWhJSIfnTdCJwWABbJcJ5gQB5QgBxZEID9wBXSEIrG+QAOSJ0AEd71hGn+xEFwuDz3dRHIZSTAgQiwgB6AVmBBOS3AACY1hstsZhERWBhnjsiMgPIQcMh7oQcRgANyEVgeFQxEywJ6oCnqQm4wgCWAjEaEABGe2sdMF93AhHsIxwUocUtJ5MpvP5hBchEgxmQeEIHjQhHuOvAN20aMY9AtnUh0OAsPhiNwyMWywAzJiyNjufi9kSFWSKVTcWKJVyNVqBIRWYQxIgROgxmorVCYfbMEA)

Comment: Your playground code has one of the Z's lowercase.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Thanks, missed that. I write a lot of these on my phone and I have to write the code twice (once in the playground and then manually copying it into SE because playground doesn't let you select text on mobile), so there's room for a lot of little mistakes. In this case the code still works, because `z` evaluates to `any` because it isn't defined, but that throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 38 characters

```
*\Cthree*two*one*g\Po*=@column@end
*=0
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '*\Cthree*two*one*g\Po*=@column@end;*=0' <<< 'There are three of you here; after this round there will be two; but only one of you will go shop for up to $20,000.'
91
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYuxCoMwGIT3PsUNnUIpwVUEoS/QoaNLrH9UiDmJCeLTp9Ghwx3H3XejLCZn1b3iFERU3KnoRY3dm6ppv3Rp8a344aYanfNnkiAwRRcOWhxMONsaxkYJZZg3BCY/lHjS@@wc@vLYWaNPEfTuKPZ/X8BIbBNXWAakFZG4V/qhtX7@AA) / [Try all <s>test</s> collected cases online!](https://tio.run/##nVPbbtNAEH2uv2IaQp1ESeumQqKtjIoqVHhARahvaYQ29viirnei3TXBpJX4Gj6MHwkzdhuoUB@oZK3HO2f2nDOzXihXbFJMtLIIk7fg0fkviXIYD4KdWXhVIO9LzhcWESiDhmqQ3VNQmUfLidKBpdqkHAp6VWoNC65Y0Sksag9kdMPLtroF5ASuoCVkZKFegifoT6NxFEX74Tw@PuzImXIs54ylfMw1u5w8fH2vDJICMweVauS0MhN@cN6WJoeEjFelcZ3uMdNoTStMYdHAd7QETFsRqyURzScpqxK24x5DW@5n1raSn1mb0z58VD4pxAv3VyYyYTtoXOnLryhNmk6Ptl26WtGlwQuS9kz/2X36Y4vvxst220FxO9tH0q@26UlaViKAjNKQWExLxluev0HnZLhL1yQF19eWyqqqDWnKS@edOFig726LMrJ4wZMny9XEl68x@QNaSKNIWN@j0r5ouhk6qpBZauG8AcM0OQn2qNV/TinCBekM9oBjadt5obRGk6OgomAYBEu@Gj6D8BZeTpjCQRc8ek95vTYhhB/Msvb8/oyu1hK8@7ZEHlXK4eVNGARyc0sB8Qq9/np3@@/MzuZ3vVNIKdixbXXc6w8AuTcwEWhb1WO2A1r6gxwrdeBs0gYQbkbX563hETsdsc1Rfv2JRvFZQrquzBmaNBjF0SaEYS8Idv7Hk6gYDKC/ftEquIM3MXANDIewt9fpYx9t7uTk@Pju14@frPL2IXMve9jjuPMl0fqP7Q7B3lum2ewvXBw/BZ3Pt@TSV3GVsuvNbw)